# Fetch custom attribute from Active Directory into CRM

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a custom attribute `EmployeeNumber` in AD, while creating CRM users when I write `UserName` for e.g *Imran.Ahmed* it automatically fetches some information from AD and fills form with that information ie *first name, last name and phone number etc*. Now I have added one more field in CRM to store Employee number in CRM. But CRM is not fetching it from AD.

How can I get information of custom attribute `EmployeeNumber` from AD to CRM form? I have been searching on internet and found some links that are saying that we have to write a plugin or call Javascript from CRM form but is there any way through which I can automatically get information from AD?

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any AD side configurations to sync extra columns into CRM system user record. Or how to add more data to pull in the platform service when you tab out the username. Am sure you are not gonna get that information/control over that integration from Product team.

You can try [this codeplex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=updatecrm2011fromad) solution by reverse engineering/extending it to achieve the requirement. Or some Graph API calls to achieve it in some timely jobs.

We have our internal HR system to read/sync such data using SSIS + Kingswaysoft connector into CRM.